# Cannot convert images to a link using anchor tag in image carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

first post on here!

I've been having issues when using the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/DvZjLz).

I tried putting the img inside an anchor tag to make the images of the carousel links to the pages I wanted, but when I do so it completely affects the way the pictures are displayed.

Here is what the carousel looks like when I add  around img and change the code in the CSS replacing "img" by "a"

[image]

Here is what it looks like without the anchor tags

[image]

There might be a simple solution to this but I am a beginner hence my difficulty with this, would be more than grateful if anyone could help!

I have tried changing the CSS code, but I do not know if I need to change the js as well

```js
var angle = 0;

function galleryspin(sign) {
  spinner = document.querySelector("#spinner");
  if (!sign) {
    angle = angle + 45;
  } else {
    angle = angle - 45;
  }
  spinner.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-transform: rotateY(" + angle + "deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(" + angle + "deg); transform: rotateY(" + angle + "deg);");
}
```

```css
div#carousel {
 perspective: 1200px;
 background: transparent;
 padding-top: 5%;
 font-size: 0;
 margin-bottom: 3rem;
 overflow: hidden;
 }

figure#spinner {
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 height: 400px;
 transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px;
 transition: 1s;
 object-fit: contain;
 }

figure#spinner img {
 width: 40%;
 max-width: 425px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 30%;
 transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px;
 outline: 1px solid transparent;
 }

figure#spinner img:nth-child(1) {
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
 }

figure#spinner img:nth-child(2) {
 transform: rotateY(45deg);
 }

figure#spinner img:nth-child(3) {
 transform: rotateY(90deg);
 }

figure#spinner img:nth-child(4) {
 transform: rotateY(135deg);
 }

figure#spinner img:nth-child(5) {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

figure#spinner img:nth-child(6) {
 transform: rotateY(225deg);
 }

figure#spinner img:nth-child(7) {
 transform: rotateY(270deg);
 }

figure#spinner img:nth-child(8) {
 transform: rotateY(315deg);
 }

div#carousel~span {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 5%;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 2rem;
 transition: 0.6s color;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -6rem;
 border-bottom: none;
 line-height: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
            <figure id="spinner">
                <img src="./Resources/Images/weeks/week1.png" alt>
                <img src="./Resources/Images/weeks/week2.png" alt>
                <img src="./Resources/Images/weeks/week3.png" alt>
                <img src="./Resources/Images/weeks/week4.png" alt>
                <img src="./Resources/Images/weeks/week5.png" alt>
                <img src="./Resources/Images/weeks/week6.png" alt>
                <img src="./Resources/Images/weeks/week7.png" alt>
                <img src="./Resources/Images/weeks/week8.png" alt>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <span style="float:left" class="ss-icon" onclick="galleryspin('')">&lt;</span>
        <span style="float:right" class="ss-icon" onclick="galleryspin('-')">&gt;</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I did not include the code since it has HTML/CSS and JS elements and did not want to make the post too big that is why I included the link to the codepen

Comment: Is this what you mean? Like I said I am a beginner really so I'm not sure what you exactly expect when you say that

Comment: I have imported your CodePen into the question.  However, the images in the code don't match what you show in the figures.  Is the CodePen your current work?

Comment: I have replaced the images in the original codepen with my personal images displayed in the screenshots :) by the way thanks a lot for the help in formatting

Comment: I have now added the code I am using myself based on the codepen

Comment: In the description you said you replaced images with links.  Yet, your updated code still shows images and no links.  Regardless, the problem is caused by changing the slides from images to links. It breaks the carousel css rules.  To fix the problem you will need to modify the css  so that it applies to your new slide structure.  This [example](https://jsfiddle.net/t5o7nm6v/show) will get your started.